# Do webmail use http protocol to send emails?

Tags: http, email

I know that smtp is the default protocol used to send mail. But I have read that http protocol is used by webmail(such as Hotmail, yahoo  etc)  to send mail from your desktop to mail server which then uses smtp to forward it to destination server. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

No. Webmail provides a HTTP interface to the client and they might store the mails written in a database or push them via whatever protocol (http, soap...) to another server - but at the end they have to use SMTP because that's what all other mail servers speak and thus this is the way to deliver mail to recipients outside the Webmails domain.

Comment: So http can be used to send mail to another server?

Comment: There is no standard for that. But the mail provider might have some internal APIs used for deliver mail inside their own infrastructure. But, I'm sure their are not for public use and not accessible from outside their infrastructure. And of course, if you have a webmail access you could use it to deliver mail with it wiht a script which emulates the browsers behavior - which would also be delivery over HTTP with a non-standard API.

Comment: Smtp is not enabled by default in windows. So to compose and send a mail from your system to mail server should happen over http/https. Right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. All the mail clients are using SMTP (or sometimes vendor-specific protocols like MS-Exchange or lotus Notes), there is no need to enable anything on the client. Only the mail server itself must provide an SMTP server.

Comment: http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/simple-mail-transport-protocol-smtp/.  This Web page shows that smtp feature is not enabled and shows how to enable it. There are also other websites which site how to enable smtp. Would you please check on the above  link??

Comment: This is for SMTP *server*, e.g. the server which should receive the mal and forward it to another server or the recipient. It has nothing to do with the client, which all speak SMTP w/o having anything to enable on the OS. Maybe you should get familiar with how SMTP or any other client/server scenarios work.